# Simulating drawing dice from an urn with pymc

Tags: python, pymc

(cross posting from https://stats.stackexchange.com/ since question was marked as off topic for that site)

Trying to do http://greenteapress.com/thinkbayes/html/thinkbayes004.html#toc23 in pymc (essentially just pulling a die from an urn and rolling it a few times)

```
import pymc as mc

die_faces = [4,6,8,12,20]
die_tosses = [x-1 for x in [6,8,7,7,5,4]] # 3 is a 4 on 0th indexed dice

which_die = mc.Categorical('which_die', [1./len(die_faces) for _ in range(len(die_faces))])

#imp = 0 # impossible
imp = 0.00000000000001  # impossible
die_probs = [[(1./face_count if i<face_count else imp) for i in range(max(die_faces))] 
            for face_count in die_faces]

@mc.deterministic
def die_results(which_die=which_die):
    return die_probs[which_die]

observation = mc.Categorical('obs', die_results, value=die_tosses, observed=True, size=len(die_tosses))

model = mc.Model([which_die, die_results, observation])
map_ = mc.MAP( model )
map_.fit() #stores the fitted variables' values in foo.value
mcmc = mc.MCMC( model )
mcmc.sample( 50000, 25000 )


die_data = mcmc.trace('which_die')[:]

for i in range(len(die_faces)):
    print 1.*list(die_data).count(i)/len(die_data)
```

This code seems to essentially get the expected answers (off a bit from known exact answer).

The issue is that it would seem to be more logical/correct to use a value of 0 for impossible.   When I do use that I get the following error (intermittently):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manydice.py", line 19, in <module>
    observation = mc.Categorical('obs', die_results, value=die_tosses, observed=True, size=len(die_tosses))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc/distributions.py", line 3179, in __init__
    verbose=verbose, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 772, in __init__
    if not isinstance(self.logp, float):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 929, in get_logp
    raise ZeroProbability(self.errmsg)
pymc.Node.ZeroProbability: Stochastic obs's value is outside its support, or it forbids its parents' current values.
```

Is there a more idiomatic and/or correct way to represent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908845/pymc-getting-zero-or-close-to-zero-categorical-likelihood/25909508#25909508) where the solution was to use a Multinomial instead of a Categorical variable.

There's also a [similar thread on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pymc/eXBEjeVf4q4) where the solution is exactly what you did: make the probability very close, but equal, to zero.

Lastly, it is very common when dealing with probabilities that you cannot have something with zero probability, so I don't think there's a better way to solve the problem than setting the probability very close to 0. Keeping in mind that probabilities that small are, in practice, "impossible" anyway.

However, this problem doesn't have a clear cut answer. If you're interested, there are some lengthy conversations and philosophical debate on what it means to have [zero probability or impossibilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41107/zero-probability-and-impossibility) on the mathematics site. (Another similar problem: is the value of 0 divided by 0 infinity or zero?)